# Jenkins + Gerrit Trigger Not Automatically Building

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins does not seem to be automatically pulling in changes that need to be reviewed from Gerrit.

We're using Gerrit Trigger.

Also If I try to manually trigger some, it seems like nothing ever happens.

The "control" in the Gerrit Trigger management area, doesn't seem to much... flashes either "starting", "stopping" or "restarting"

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: How did you configure your jobs, which should be started by the Gerrit trigger? Can you provide a screenshot from your job configuration?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I was just having the same problem, and it had to do with the default Gerritt setting in my job for matching branches.
In your job, under Gerritt Trigger, if your Branches Pattern says "**", make sure the Type is set to Path, or else it won't match any branches.

Comment: You sir are a saver. Had been struggling with the configuration for 2 hours before I found your answer.

Comment: qq, if the Pattern under the branches section has Path: **/*my-truck*  what does this mean, any branch and then what does /*my-truck*/ mean?

Answer (score 13):

I've actually stumbled over the same problem and it took me a while to figure out the UI, since I thought the branch and project configuration belongs to `Dynamic Trigger Configuration`. The configuration will basically need to look like this: [image]

*Note:* my configuration uses the `Silent Mode`, since I don't want the plug-in to communicate back to gerrit.

Comment: Please note that, at least in my experience, the project name (`my-project` in this example), must be *exactly* the same as the full name of the project that you see in Gerrit.